# Could be misleading using some terms to describe certain phenomena?

Tags: terminology

I am implementing a series of comparative analyses related to Low Complexity Regions in some organisms. Given that these regions show a wide range of length (measured in amino acids) and different characteristics, writing my report I would like to use "mosaicism" to describe this interspersion. Given that the term mosaicism is used to describe when someone have two or more genetically different cells inside his or her organism, I am in doubt if using this word could be misleading or, given that the term per-se indicates a set of gussets that compose a picture, to consider it somewhat elegant given that is clear enough what I am talking about.

Obliged

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give some more background (or provide helpful links) regarding what "Low Complexity Regions" are and explain their characteristics. Based on what you did say, I'm not sure "mosaic" is the best way of describing the phenomenon.

Comment: Regardless of what term you choose, define at the beginning how you'll be using it for the purposes of your analyses.  Clarity is probably more important the precise word you settle on

Comment: Do you know what a mosaic is? Do you really understand why the term mosaicism is employed. I am not clear what the phenomenon is you are describing. You use the word interspersion. What is wrong with that? Can you draw a diagram in which this phenomenon is compared to a non-interspersed reference so we can see whether the word fits or another may be better, or indeed whether an additional adjective will remove any ambiguity.